# Ways to validate that an EOA has authority over a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

How to validate that an EOA account has authority over a smart contract account, within solidity code?

If msg.sender is a smart contract, is there a way in solidity to find out who deployed that smart contract / who the “owner” is, within the code?

Let’s say you have a service (implemented by a smart contract) that you allow EOA accounts and smart contract accounts to register and associate additional info about themselves that can then be looked up by the public.

EOA accounts can send a transaction, with the ‘extra info’ as parameters and because msg.sender identifies the EOA  securely, the service will register their address and the additional information.  If this registration service were well known (for example ENS), then new contracts could have functionality built-in to do this.  But already-deployed contracts weren’t programmed to do so, and new contracts may simply choose not to do so.

So one alternative is for an EOA account to register on behalf of the smart contract.  But there must be some kind of verification otherwise anyone can register info for a contract and it needs some kind of authorization.

One possibility I thought of is to require the smart contract to send funds to your service as part of verification, since a lot of smart contracts are designed to allow the owner or approved accounts to send money from the contract to an address.

The EOA could state it’s intention to verify an (smart contract) address through one transaction, and the service could respond with the exact amount that has to be paid from the smart contract address to verify authority to register on behalf.

EOA ——> (intent to register for 0xcontractaddr) —-> “registration service” smart contract

EOA <——— (amount that should be sent) <——— “registration service” smart contract

0xcontractaddr ———> (amount) ——> “registration service” smart contract

I’m thinking that there could be an issue due to the public nature of blockchain.  A hacker can try to interrupt by reading the results of the first transaction and send another registration request but then the response if randomized may be a different amount.  This would also theoretically take one block to find out.

The amount could have a lot of variance down to the wei, so the attacker can not cycle through a small number of verification amounts.  If the hacker could control the smart contract into sending an exact amount to a specific address, this would be a problem.  Alternatively, the attacker can try to do a denial-of-service if their request invalidates the earlier request, or precedes the legitimate request.

Is this something that is being done now on the chain, are there other approaches, and any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: Why do you need to validate that someone owns a contract? Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to require the contract to implement a `getOwner()` function.

Comment: Thanks @Ismael for the suggestion!